# How to use Link Type:External in FlexBuilder

Tags: apache-flex

, I want to use swc library with External link type in flashbuilder, but it always report errors that class not found. Is anyone known how to use this link type?

Comment: Give us the error message!

Comment: VerifyError: Error #1014: Class (every class i want use from external swc) could not be found.